# Quartz trigger reset after every hour

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have created a Simple Trigger using Quartz library. Now the trigger executes a job after 8 mins. I start it at 00:00 and it runs till 00:56 fine.The next execution should happen at 01:04 but it starts at 01:00 and same thing happens after every start of the hour. To tackle this we have to create 2 schedulers for odd and even hours to start at 00:00 and 01:04 respectively.
Is there any limitation to the library of there is a way to tackle this.

```
        return SimpleScheduleBuilder
                .repeatSecondlyForever(Integer.parseInt(schedule.getValue()))
                .withRepeatCount(schedule.getRepeatCount());
    }
```

Comment: I suppose ```Integer.parseInt(schedule.getValue())``` yields the value ```480```, but what are you doing with ```.withRepeatCount```. Do you want to limit the count of executions by this? Why? There is not enough detail in your question, so it is hard to answer.